# Can we assign multi category to a article in Joomla 1.6

Tags: joomla

In Joomla! 1.6, there is a new feature that we can define a endless nested categories.
But is there a feature about assign multi categories to a article?
Or is there any extension can do this in joomla! 1.6 or 1.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Flexicontent, or SOBI, but not K2 or default Joomla

Comment: Flexicontent works just what I need. But it working not very well with artcats. Artcats provide a module that can display selected categories list. But change artcats to support it will not be too hard. Thanks ,Jeepstone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a new component. Go to:
http://usjoomlagurus.com/Extensions/Multi-Categories-For-Articles/flypage.tpl.html

Answer (score 0):

With a default Joomla setup that is not possible.

As this is a pretty common thing one may want or need such an extension may very well exist. Check the [Joomla Extensions site/directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/).